# How to prove CLT for predictable quadratic variation $\langle X_n \rangle$ for a martingale $X_n$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, probability-limit-theorems, local-martingales

Im interested in higher order inference (like Edgeworth expansions for iid case) of martingales, and reading series of paper by Per Mykland (1993, 1995, etc). In it, the core condition for the higher order expansion is the CLT(Central Limit Theorem) for the (predictable) quadratic variation of the martingale.

So, simply put, can anyone come up with a good way to prove $ n^{1/2}(\langle X_n \rangle - E[ \langle X_n \rangle ]) $ converges to a normal random variable, without assuming a lot more than the conditions necessary for proving the CLT for $ X_n $?

Comment: Meaning of CLT ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you write down what kind of results you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, tried editing. Hope it got a little clearer?

Comment: @numpynp Not sure if there's much hope for this. If $X_n$ has deterministic quadratic variation (e.g. Brownian motion) then this sequence is degenerate. Not sure about other processes.